# VLC's image appears darker in Ubuntu than in Windows

Tags: 11.04, laptop, vlc

When I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 on the same computer as my Windows 7, it shows videos a little darker than usual. I have a Dell laptop. The problem starts after about 10 to 15 minutes into the movie.

Comment: Actually now that you mention it i tried to check it with the power connected and it did not go dark on me. How to solve this then?

Comment: If it's not connected to the AC adapter, it's a power saving feature.

Comment: Go to system>power saving and adjust the settings to your liking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Power Manager:

And Slide the Display bar to a higher value and/or uncheck Dim display when idle.

[image: pwr]

Comment: Vlc probably has a feature that keeps the display from being dimmed, doesn't it? Most other players do . I mention it cause it doesn't sound like a good idea to me to disable the dimming just for one application

Comment: I can't find anything in the VLC preferences .

Comment: Hye Uri thanks. Yes that solved it. That was the problem all along.